# Make padding-left ,padding-right responsive

Tags: css, angular, sass, responsive

I want to make responsive `padding-left` and `padding-right` in code below:

```
<ng-template #addnote>
    <div class="styleaddnote">
      <button class="addnotebtn" (click)="openDialog()">ADD NOTE</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I have written this code, I wrote a new code for all `@media`, but doesn't work very well. The distance between left and right isn't correct in some `@media` width. I want to set a button in the center.

```
@media(min-width:600px){
  .styleaddnote {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -5%;
  width:50%;
  padding: 0 5% 0 10%;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 15%;
  padding-left: 0%;
  }
}
@media(min-width:700px){
  .styleaddnote {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width:50%;
  padding: 0 5% 0 10%;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 15%;
  padding-left: 0%;
  }
}
@media(min-width:800px){
  .styleaddnote {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 10%;
  width:50%;
  padding: 0 5% 0 10%;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 15%;
  padding-left: 0%;
  }
}
@media(min-width:900px){
  .styleaddnote {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15%;
  width:50%;
  padding: 0 5% 0 10%;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 15%;
  padding-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

Please, can you share with me any idea how to make it responsive? I think that have a way for it but I don't find a good way that works well.

Thanks

Comment: What have you set for devices with width less than 600px? And why are you having to change the padding at all if it can be expressed in % terms? Is your button defined in responsive units (e.g. %)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

three notes:

1.-if you use `padding:0 5% 0 10%` **not** use `padding-top:..padding-bottom:...`

2.-you first indicate the padding by defect -for the less screen resolution- without media

```
.styleaddnote {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15%;
  width:50%;
  padding: 0 5% 0 10%;
  }
```

After write the `@media` -only the changes over the before css rule- for each change of screen dimension:

```
@media(min-width:600px){
  .styleaddnote {
     padding: 0 5% 0 10%;
  }
}
@media(min-width:700px){
  .styleaddnote {
     padding: 0 15% 0 12%;
  }
}
...
```

3.-Normally you don't use arbritary "break-points" -you use for 600px, 700px,800px... For example in bootstrap you use 576px, 768px, 992px, 1200px and 1400px see [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/), in tailwinds (see the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints)) 640px, 768px,1024px, 1280px and 1576px